# Making a program that reads input from user and distincts lower case from upper case, and checks if a character is introduced twice

Tags: javascript, java, netbeans

I have to make a program that asks the user to enter capital letters and when a lower case carácter is introduced, display"true" if you have previously entered two consecutive characters which are the same, and display "false" if there haven't been two consecutive characters which were the same.

I cannot use any method of clases and Character String or the use of vectors.

So far, i have been using scanner class to read the user's input as a Char, and asked again, using while, while it is an upper character.
I have no idea on how to check if a character is introduced twice in a row.
Im sorry if myjava knowleadge is very little as i been starting to learn last month.

I expect the user to input any letter, lower case or upper case.
The program will stop when the user enters a lower case letter

Example of Output:

LETTER: A //Entered by user



LETTER: C //Entered by user



LETTER: C //Entered by user



LETTER: P //Entered by user



LETTER: s //Entered by user



true     //Program stops, true is displayed as C was entered twice consecutively

I found the answer, it is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

     char lastinput;
     char input = sc.next().charAt(0);
     boolean con = false;

   while (input>='A'&&input<='Z'){
   lastinput = input;

   input = sc.next().charAt(0);
     if (input==lastinput){
       con = true;
     }
     else{}
    }
   System.out.println(con);
     }
    }
```

All this through Net Beans.

Comment: What is a *"small box one"*?

Comment: Can you clarify the (homework?) "problem" a little more? You need to just read until you get a lowercase character and then the output is either `true` or `false`? You example shows `true` as the output. If there was an `X` between the two `C` inputs, would the output be `false`?

Comment: lower case letter

Comment: Ok i will edit the post to make it more clear, its my first post so i am still learning how to do it properly

Comment: The best policy is to make sure our show all of the following: (1) the kind of input you expect, (2) the kind of output you expect and (3) the code you have written so far. Without #3, nobody is going to want to help you. That's called "doing it for you" and not "helping you with a problem."

Comment: Ok, i will add the code i've got so far, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Okey, i found the answer to my question. What do i do now? Post an 'Answer'? Edit the post?

Comment: Where did you "find" the answer? If it's on SO, vote to close your own post as a duplicate of the question where the answer is. If you developed it yourself, thank the person who helped (@MrFishman) and accept that answer. In either case, give an up-vote for the suggestion.

Comment: I figued it out, and gave an upvote, ty yoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep your last String in the variable. Then if next letter is the same set another boolean variable to true. Then if somone type the lowercase letter break the while loop and print boolean variable.

Comment: You should use nextChar() instead of nextLine() and save it in char variable because you just want to get one letter. Then will be easier to check if this char is lower or uppercase. I find for you how to do it: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/character_islowercase.htm

Comment: It says that method "nextChar()" doesn't exist. To get only one character i have been trying to use  " char input = sc.next().charAt(0);"  to read the user input as a char

Comment: You don't even need a `boolean` variable; when you break the loop, the value will always be `false` and until you break the loop the value will be `true`.

Comment: But if user did not give two same uppercase letters and then just give one lowercase, vaule will be still false. OP wants to break the loop when user gives one lowercase letter not when two letters are the same :)